# React component lifecycle and initiating asynchronous processes

Tags: reactjs

Consider a ReactJS scenario were a stateful component is responsible to fetch information from an outside HTTP API and present it. 
It is also responsible for refetching that information in reaction to DOM events (e.g. button clicks) or time intervals.

If I correctly understand the new ReactJS 16.3 lifecycle:

- `componentDidMount` is the proper place to start the initial fetch.
- `componentWillUnmount` should be used to cancel any pending fetch.

However, I've a question regarding additional fetches in reaction to asynchronous events, such a button click handler or a `setInterval` handler:

- Should the event handler schedule the new state using `setState` (e.g. 
  `setState({loading:true})`) **and** also start the HTTP fetch even before the new state is committed?
- Or instead only schedule the new state in the handler using `setState` and only start the HTTP fetch in the `componentDidUpdate`, after the new state is committed to the DOM.

A similar scenario is if a new fetch is required because the component's `props` changed. In this case, I assume the `componentDidUpdate` is always the correct place to start the new fetch, namely because `getDerivedStateFromProps` or `shouldComponentUpdate` happen in the *render phase*.

Thanks,
Pedro

Comment: Sounds to me like you understand it perfectly. Are you concerned about something? In regards to your two choices, it doesn't matter except that putting something that will call `setState` in `componentDidUpdate` you need to make sure you're not causing an infinite loop

Comment: The `setState` would always be done on the event handler. Is the HTTP fetch that I have doubts: should it be on the handler or only on the `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: what does the HTTP fetch do? are you getting some data back from it that you want to display?

Comment: Yes. It fetches data that is presented by the component.

Comment: how is going to present data without calling `setState` ?

Comment: I always call `setState`, namely in the event handlers. My question is about the proper place to start the fetch: 1) Immediately on the event handler (where I call `setState`) or 2) On the `componentDidUpdate` after the state is committed?

Comment: You're not understanding me. If you initiate the fetch in `componentDidUpdate` then you WILL be calling `setState` as a result, because you need to call `setState` once your fetch returns otherwise your fetch isn't doing anything!! and if you do that, it will trigger another `componentDidUpdate` and you will have an infinite loop unless you're comparing old and new props, which is fine.. but just be aware of that

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. Yes, `componentDidUpdate` is called multiple times, namely when the fetch is started and when the fetch is ended. Is doesn't enter a loop because the `componentDidUpdate` only start a fetch if the state is `loading`. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's easier for everyone to see some sample code. This is how I would do it if I was not using Redux:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ItemView extends Component {
  state = {
    fetching: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchItems();

    // Fetch items every 10 seconds
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.fetchItems();
    }, 10 * 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);

    if (this.state.fetching) {
      this.isUnmounted = true;
    }
  }

  fetchItems = () => {
    this.setState({
      fetching: true
    });

    return fetch("https://api.example.org/items").then(response => {
      if (!this.isUnmounted) {
        this.setState({
          fetching: false,
          items: response.json().items
        })
      }
    }).catch(e => {
      if (!this.isUnmounted) {
        this.setState({
          fetching: false,
          error: e.message
        });
      }
    })
  };
}
```

Now, to reply your questions:

1. `getDerivedStateFromProps` is a sync operation which is triggered after the initial render and after new props have been received. Therefore, I would not suggest putting async operations here. Also it is part of the render phase (check the second point).
2. React lifecycle has two phases: The `render` and the `commit` phase. React compares the changes to be done in the `render` phase and lifecycles in this phase can be triggered multiple times before the `commit` occurs. Changes to the DOM are made in the `commit` phase. `ComponentDidUpdate` is called after the `commit` phase, therefore I would suggest it's the right place to do async operations so that you can display the loading state till you receive a response from the API and you don't trigger multiple times the request.
3. Last but not least, I would use Redux and move the fetch logic outside the component so we don't have to deal with race conditions (for instance, cases like component is already unmounted till we receive a response from the api, or parent component updates the props meanwhile).

If you do not want to use the `isUnmounted` pattern ([check here why](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html)), you might consider using cancellable promises.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I understood it correctly, you start the fetch immediately on the event handler, event before the new state is committed?

Comment: Yes. It's not necessary to wait for the new state to be committed. If you really require so, `setState`'s second argument is a callback. You can pass an anonymous function there which fetches the content from the API. @PedroFelix